# Errors Plotting a Restricted Cubic Spline with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, splines

I would like to use `ggplot2` to illustrate a fit using a restricted cubic spline using `geom_smooth()` but it seems to be working incorrectly.  Here is a short example:

```
# rms package Contains Restricted Cubic Splines (RCS)
library(rms)
library(ggplot2)

# Load Data
data(cars)

# Model Fit with RCS
fit <- lm(speed ~ rcs(dist, 5), data=cars)

# Obtain Diagnostic Data
plot.dat <- cbind(cars, fitted=fitted(fit))

# Compare Smooth to Actual
ggplot(data=plot.dat) +
  geom_point(aes(x=dist, y=speed)) +
  geom_smooth(aes(x=dist, y=speed), method="lm", 
              formula=y ~ rcs(x, 5), se=FALSE, colour="blue") +
  geom_line(aes(y=fitted, x=dist), size=1.25, colour="red")
```

This results in the following image:
[Comparison of Splines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQu9y.jpg)
I am not sure why `geom_smooth()` is not giving the correct results.  Clearly there is a work-around (as illustrated above), but is there a way to make `geom_smooth()` produce the correct results?

Comment: I wonder if this will be easy? The `rcs`-function is part of the 'rms'-world. As with the case with 'ggplot2'-world functions, the 'rms' functions expect other helper functions and structures to be available in the environment. There are separate `Predict` methods for the `ols` function, an analog of `lm`. This requires specifying a datadist object as an option. When I run `Predict(ols(speed ~ rcs(dist, 5),data=cars)) `, I get the same results as your `fitted`. When I try to offer "ols" as a method to `geom_smooth`, I get an error.

Comment: I didn't realize that there was a ggplot.Predict function: An unanswered question that sets up an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33039815/cropped-plot-from-ggplot-predict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been a long time, but I finally recognized the problem, and I thought I would post it here for those interested.  Internally, `geom_smooth()` will create a sequence of the predictor at which to plot the predicted response.  As this sequence is spaced out across the range of the x-axis, the knot points selected by `rcs()` inside of `geom_smooth()` will differ from the knot points selected by `rcs()` on the original data.  To address this, you need to pass in the correct knot points.

```
# rms package Contains Restricted Cubic Splines (RCS)
library(rms)
library(ggplot2)

# Load Data
data(cars)

# Model Fit with RCS
fit <- lm(speed ~ rcs(dist, 5), data=cars)

# Obtain Diagnostic Data
plot.dat <- cbind(cars, fitted=fitted(fit))

# Compare Smooth to Actual
ggplot(data=plot.dat) +
  geom_point(aes(x=dist, y=speed)) +
  geom_smooth(aes(x=dist, y=speed), method="lm", 
              formula=y ~ rcs(x, quantile(plot.dat$dist, probs = c(0.05, 0.275, 0.5, 0.725, 0.95))), se=FALSE, colour="blue") +
  geom_line(aes(y=fitted, x=dist), colour="red")
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to integrate this with `geom_smooth` but I can do it with `ggplot.Predict` from the rms package:

```
ddist <- datadist(cars)
options(datadist='ddist')

fit <- ols(speed~  rcs(dist,5),data=cars,
               x=TRUE, y=TRUE)

ggplot(Predict(fit))+geom_point(data=cars, aes(x=dist, y=speed))
```

[image]